# Looking for a story where a person is threatened with repeated murder

Tags: story-identification, clones

A novel I read in the early 80's but was most likely published in the 70's(?) begins with a woman being woken up.  She is shown pictures of herself and it is explained to her that these were earlier clones of her and that she is herself a clone.  She is pressured to perform some task and threatened with similar treatment if she tries to escape.

Can anyone help me recall the title?

Comment: I have a vague feeling that there was a John Varley Eight Worlds story with a similar plot, but I can't place it exactly. Of course, any universe with clone-n-backup immortality is a candidate for this plot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a *forcing people to do things by serially murdering them* sub-plot in John Varley's novel [The Ophiuchi Hotline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ophiuchi_Hotline).

Other things that may be memorable about the novel include a trip far into Trans-Plutarian space with pilot whose body has been heavily sculpted to the point where her head is the widest part of the body; several instances of people being active in two or more bodies at once; and partial answers to questions about the Invaders and what is to become of humanity.

Comment: Just dug up a copy.  The scene where she wakes for the third time and is shown a script of exactly what she said the previous two times she was cloned.  Very surreal and powerful scene.  Maybe thats why I thought of it as pictures, but it's definately Ophiuchi Hotline.  Thanks.

Comment: Heh. I'm on a Varley roll this week. Now I need someone to ask about *Titan* or something...