# Probably 70's era novel about a woman repeatedly murdered, restored as clone with only memories up to last backup

Tags: story-identification, novel

Science fiction novel from 70s or early 80's I think, about a woman repeatedly murdered and restored as a clone with only memories up to last backup.

The novel is about her search for her murderer and his/her motives. In this society cosmetic genetic mods are normal - protagonist likes her legs lengthened and lower legs covered in long fur.

At one point another clone appears who is a deep space pilot and is modded to have only one arm and one leg, so that in zero G she can get around her spaceship through special tunnels.

Another clone is a deep space asteroid(?) miner and is modded to be photosynthetic.

SPOILER FOLLOWS:

> The murderer turns out to be the woman's own illegal clone - a male. Killing her out of jealousy I think?

Comment: Hi there. That's some good info already; just in case, please take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. For instance how old is "old"? 90s, 60s? Any recollection of the cover?

Comment: I think it was 70's. No idea at all of cover. I was thinking it was Ursula Le Guin or Vonda McIntire but searched their bibiographies with no success...

Comment: FYI I also posted this same question on the GoodReads group "whats the name of that book"

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/looking-for-a-story-where-a-person-is-threatened-with-repeated-murder

Answer (score 13):

That is definitely *[The Ophiuchi Hotline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ophiuchi_Hotline)* by John Varley, which contains all the elements you mention.

Comment: MinMcQ, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checmark on the left. Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved, and reward both you and Mike with some reputation :)